# Generate XSD from Java classes with notion of interface, is it possible?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm currently working on a project with XSD file exposing our internal Java model. My problem is that I can't manage to have the XSD reflecting the use of an interface ... The Java model is quiet classic :

- One interface and two implementations of this interface
- One object with a field of type interface (it's this object that I can't reflect in the xsd file)

The schema is the following : 
[image: Class diagram]

I tried to generate the XSD for the whole POC project with JAXB but I've the following error :

```
TestItf is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at TestItf(src/TestItf.java:1)
        at TestContainer.test(src/TestContainer.java:9)
        at TestContainer(src/TestContainer.java:6)
TestItf is a non-static inner class, and JAXB can't handle those.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at TestItf(src/TestItf.java:1)
        at TestContainer.test(src/TestContainer.java:9)
        at TestContainer(src/TestContainer.java:6)
te
```

My question is the following : is it possible to do what I'm trying to do ? In other words, is it possible to tell through the XSD that my object TestContainer must either contain TestImpl or TestImplBis in the field TestInstance ?

PS : I know that we can use xsd:choice, but it's a kind of hack ... I would rather specify interface so that when a new class implements TestItf no need to update the xsd:choice element

Thanks in advance guys